# Is there a fast way to update many records in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I need to replace more than 20 000 names with new names i created given the CodeID.

For example: I must update all rows that contain "dog" (which has a CodeID of 1) with "cat", and  update all rows that contain "horse" (which has a CodeID of 2) with "bird", etc.

1st SQL statement: UPDATE animalTable SET `cDescription` = "cat" WHERE `CodeID` = 1

2nd SQL statement: UPDATE animalTable SET `cDescription` = "bird" WHERE `CodeID` = 2

These statements work, but i need a faster way to do this because i have over 20 000 names.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In what form is the list of CodeId|OldName|NewName?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the question.  Can you please provide the schema for your tables or try to rephrase a little?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats the fastest way you can do it.

Or do you want update all records in a single command?

you can do a update with a join (Fixed Syntax... Havent used this one in a while)

```
UPDATE animalTable 
INNER JOIN CodeTable ON animalTable.CodeID = CodeTable.ID 
SET animalTable.cDescription = CodeTable.Description_1;
```

Another option is to split the updates into smaller batches, this will reduce the time the table is locked... But the total time of the updates will take longer (Its just an improvement of precieved Performance) You can do that by updating only certain ID ranges in each batch.

Also you could have that data in a separate table. Since the data is not normalized. Move it away so its more normalized.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just had to edit a few things: 

UPDATE animalTable INNER JOIN CodeTable ON animalTable.CodeID = CodeTable.ID SET animalTable.cDescription = CodeTable.Description_1;

 Thanks again much appreciated

Comment: is there a way to disable table locking and rollback features during an UPDATE? perhaps disable all extra feature on the entire DB? because that will be the fastest

Comment: No, those features belong in a SQL DB. You can limit the table locking by ensuring your batch size is below 5000 rows each update, so no lock escalation happens. Also with a recent version of SQL you can look into the "Delayed durability" feature which i would not suggest for production use (But it can buy you some performance under SEVERE constrains... check TechNet)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to create a temporary table that holds the translation values and update based on that.

For example:

```
create table #TRANSLATIONS
(
    from   varchar(32),
    to     varchar(32)
)
```

Then, insert the translation values:

```
insert into #TRANSLATIONS (from,to) values ('cat','dog')
```

Finally, update based on that:

```
update MYTABLE
set    myvalue = t.to
where  myvalue = t.from
from   MYTABLE m,
       #TRANSLATIONS t
```

(Untested, off the top of my head).

Comment: Like I said -- untested, off the top of my head. :-) Doesn't the 'where' clause implement the join?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`CASE`](http://www.craigsmullins.com/ssu_0899.htm) statement to update it:

```
UPDATE animaltable SET cDescription = CASE codeID WHEN 1 THEN 'cat' WHEN 2 THEN 'bird'.... END
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposind you have a file like this:

```
1,cat
2,bird
...
```

I would write a script which reads that file and executes an update for each row.

In PHP:

```
$f = fopen("file.csv","r")
while($row = fgetcsv($f, 1024)) {
    $sql = "update animalTable set cDescription = '".$row[1]."' where CodeID = ".$row[0];
    mysql_query($sql);
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: what is the 1024 in brackets?

Comment: taken from documentation (http://us.php.net/fgetcsv):
Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters). It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.0.4 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower.

Comment: how would i execute this script? sorry i'm new at mySQL.

Comment: It's PHP: you can't execute it *inside* MySQL. I was suggesting to use a script language to parse a file and execute several queries against your db so that PHP is just a sample: you can use any language that can read files and query your db (almost any language can do it)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to speed it up is to only update those records that don't already have the value you want to assign.

```
UPDATE animalTable SET cDescription = "cat" WHERE CodeID = 1 AND cDescription != "cat"
```

This approach makes the command only update those records that are not already 'cat'.

Disclaimer: I hate cats.